# Различие между context и this

Tags: java, android, context

В андроиде есть `context`-ссылка, а на самой джаве есть `this`-ссылка. Так вот в чем разница контекста от зиса и можноли пример  с контекстом а то я запутался в нем. Благодарю.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` и `Context` – это принципиально разные вещи.

`this` – это ключевое слово языка Java. `this` – это ссылка на самого себя. Ссылка на объект, для которого был вызван метод.

`Context` (в android) – это абстрактный класс, предоставляющий методы для доступа к т.н. глобальной информации (к ресурсам, классам, для управления активити, сервисами и так далее).

Непосредственными субклассами классами `Context` являются классы `ContextWrapper` и `MockContext`. В свою очередь, прямыми субклассами класса `ContextWrapper`, в том числе, являются классы `Application` и `Service`, а непрямым – класс `Activity`.

Пример с `Context`:

```
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // some actions
        }
    });
```

Здесь, для запуска кода в `UI`-потоке используется объект класса `Activity` (который является (непрямым) наследником класса `Context`).

Еще один пример с `Context`:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

Здесь в конструктор класса `LinearLayoutManager` передается объект класса `Activity`. Такой вызов, возможен, например, из фрагмента.

Из самой активити можно напрямую вызвать:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

так как `this` в методах активити является как раз объектом класса `Activity`.

Comment: можно легонкий пример с контекстом ?

Comment: @elik, Добавил.

Comment: аааа  понел хзначит любое активити в андроиде это потомок КОнтекста теперь стало ясно !спасибо